# how to change the view from UIalertview?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uialertview

please explain to me how to change UIView when I click on UIalertView which displayed form a specific

class.
don't hesitate if you know any tutorial

let's say I am currently display viewcontoller1 when I have receive special packet then I have to display another xib  based on the user selection

I have tried pushViewController in UIAlertView delegate put it doesn't work

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you add more context around what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Mohammed What do you mean by change UIView?

Comment: @Mohammed please share your code. "trying pushViewController in UIAlertView delegate" should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the UIAlertView delegates. So in the specific class you want to call from. In the header file, add  like so

```
@interface SomeClass : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
...
```

Then when the alert is alloc/init set the delegate

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
        [alert setDelegate:self];
        [alert show];
```

Within the same class as the alertView, put this delegate method in.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([alertView cancelButtonIndex] == buttonIndex){
        return;
    //Do your UIView change here
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In my case I have do what you said but with some changes SomeClass Not UIViewController it is NSobject

Comment: Then I suggest you should leave the alertView to be handled by the ViewController that your NSObject is called in. You could implement delegate methods in your NSObject, so when the object wants to call a UIAlertView, it will ask the UIViewController that called it to put one up.